# Making doughnut graph with animation using SVG

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a doughnut graph with svg and also adding a animation to it.
Currently I'm getting a trouble other parts of the graph.
There are two graph that I wanted to make :

[image]

[image]

And here is the graph that I've made this far for the first graph.

```css
.svg-item {
    width: 50%;
    animation: donutfade 1s;
}

.donut-ring {
    stroke: #F4E2E2;
}

.donut-segment-1 {
    stroke: #EA0001;
    animation: donut1 3s;
}

.donut-segment-2 {
    stroke: blue;
    animation: donut2 3s;
}

.donut-segment-3 {
    stroke: pink;
    animation: donut3 3s;
}

@keyframes donutfade {
  /* this applies to the whole svg item wrapper */
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes donut1 {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 17, 83;
    }
}

@keyframes donut2 {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 32, 85;
    }
}

@keyframes donut3 {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 49, 85;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-item">
  <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 44 44" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="10" cy="10" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="22" cy="22" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#ffff" stroke-width="12"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment donut-segment-1" cx="22" cy="22" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="12" stroke-dasharray="17 83" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment donut-segment-2" cx="22" cy="22" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="12" stroke-dasharray="32 85" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment donut-segment-3" cx="22" cy="22" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="12" stroke-dasharray="49 85" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

From the code above I kinda manage to make 2 parts of the first graph and been struggling making the third part and the others. Is there a better way to make moving doughnut graph ?
Can anyone please help me make this doughnut graph.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe you should try using `conic-gradient()` [see the fourth example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient#try_it)

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply
Thank you for your suggestion, I'm gonna need to figure how to animate the graph with the new way you have introduced me too.